# Apply Function to All Strings in Structure

Tags: python, json, utf-8, decode

I have some complicated structures I need to convert to JSON. Normally, this is fine, but sometimes, I'll get bad data like this:

```
{'FIRST_NAME': 'sdffg\xed', 'LAST_NAME': 'sdfsadf', 'MORE_INFO':['hi','blah', {'key1': 'value1'}]}
```

Simple `json.dumps(data)` gives me:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 6: ordinal not in range(128)
```

As does `json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)`.

In cases of data unreadable in utf-8, I just want it ignored. The only way I've been able to find to get what I want is to do:

```
item.decode("utf8", "ignore") if item else None
```

On every single item in the structure. So, is there either:

1. A way to do this within `json.dumps()` (preferred)?
2. A way to uniformly apply this string function to all strings and only strings in some complicated structure?

Comment: does `json.dumps(unicode(d, "utf-8", errors="ignore"))` work?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham breaks when there are sublevels like MORE_INFO in the example.

Comment: can you give a larger example of input?

Comment: Edited to put in more sublevels, though I'm not sure how that's helpful...

Comment: I asked as `json.dumps(data, ensure_ascii=False)` does not throw any error for me. I can see how it would throw an  error if I tried to `json.loads` after but it works using ensure_ascii=False.

Answer (score 0):

If all your extras characters are `latin-1` like in your example using:

```
json.dumps(d, ensure_ascii=False,encoding="latin-1")
```

will give you the correct output

```
{"FIRST_NAME": "sdffgí", "LAST_NAME": "sdfsadf", "MORE_INFO": ["hi", "blah"]}
```

To remove non ascii chars you can use:

```
d1 = json.dumps(d,ensure_ascii = False)

print (json.loads(re.sub(r'[^\x00-\x7F]','', d1))))

{u'FIRST_NAME': u'sdffg', u'LAST_NAME': u'sdfsadf', u'MORE_INFO': [u'hi', u'blah']}
```

Comment: It was just an example. The encoding could be anything.